# How to deal with textbox validation?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
Private Sub txtUserCode_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If RS!ID = txtUserCode.Text Then
        SQL = "SELECT NAME,PRIVILEDGE FROM ADMIN WHERE CODE=" & txtUserCode.Text
        Set RS = CN.Execute(SQL)
        txtUserName.Text = RS!NAME
    Else
        MsgBox "ENTER VALID NO"
        txtUserCode.Text = ""
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In this code I want to execute like:

1. If I enter the ID present in table then it'll show info but it's considering 1st record (`RS!ID(0)`) only not the next one
2. If I enter the ID which is not present in table then it should not throw error
   `3021- Requested operation requires current record` but goto else part.

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming `RS` is a recordset.

Depending on the `RS` type, you can try and `Find` a record like this:

```
RS.MoveFirst
RS.Find("[CODE]=" &  txtUserCode.Text)
If Not RS.EOF Then
    ' found!
End If
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the ADO `Find` function.